# There were injured on both sides - grammar

Tags: grammar

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/ukraine-says-30-pro-russian-insurgents-killed-071845546.html

> Avakov said Monday that pro-Russia forces in Slovyansk, a city of 125,000, were deploying large-caliber weapons and mortars in the region and there were **injured** on both sides. Government troops were facing about 800 insurgents, he said.

Is the way it's written grammatically correct? Do we not have to precede the word with **the** to denote that we are talking about a group of people?

Comment: The sentence begins with deployments and ends with injuries......there is no mention of fighting.....I think this is an abuse of journalistic style......adding **the** to the sentence will not improve it.

Comment: The sentence is correct. Indeed, groups of people often take the definite article (the poor, the homeless). This is not the case, however, though I lack a decent explanation to give you.

Comment: The definite article is used in the same way before adjectives-turned-nouns like *dead*, *injured*, meaning *dead people* or *injured people* as it is in any other setting (although note that these adjectives-turned-nouns are usually plural). Just as you would say *there were heroes on both sides*, you say *there were injured on both sides*, with no definite article.

Comment: As others say, it is correct. I think I prefer this to other options centred around that word, such as `there were injuries on both sides`. Perhaps it would be too much of the `s` sound if `injuries` was used.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: The sentence is out of context; the rest of the article discusses the fighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would mention *the* injured, it would mean you are referring to a groups of injured people that you have mentioned before:

> Twelve people were injured. The injured were on both sides.

However, we are *not* talking about a specific group of injured (people) here. In that case, we use the *indefinite article*, which in the singular is **a**, and in the plural is empty (zero-article).
Compare "I have an apple" => "I have apples".

In the same way, the writer used the indefinite article correctly like this:

> There was an injured [person].
>   There were injured [people].

As was mentioned in the comments, *injuries* could well have been used instead of injured, but neither is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, you don't need to use the article.

In this instance, the expanded noun phrase is:

```
and there were injured [people] on both sides
```

However, because we know that we're talking about people, it's been elided.